# My AdMob ads do not work in my app

Tags: java, android, admob, logcat

My AdMob advertisements does not show up neither on screen of USB debugging device nor in logcat. As ad unit ID I have set one from https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads to obey AdMob policies. Real ads are not showing either (I noticed it when downloading my app through Google Play). In logcat none of these two logs is showing which is really confusing. Maybe I should implement that ad in Fragments which are handled by this Activity (I mean HomeFragment and CameraFragment). I did not get any AdMob account suspensions probably because I did not get any notifications when checking my AdMob consoles. Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;


import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.Login.LoginActivity;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.R;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.Utils.BottomNavigationViewHelper;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.Utils.MainfeedListAdapter;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.Utils.SectionsPagerAdapter;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.Utils.UniversalImageLoader;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.Utils.ViewCommentsFragment;
import com.stek.ca_ltd.memestackupdating.models.Photo;

import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        MainfeedListAdapter.OnLoadMoreItemsListener{

    @Override
    public void onLoadMoreItems() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLoadMoreItems: displaying more photos");
        HomeFragment fragment = (HomeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
        //CameraFragment fragment2 = (CameraFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager_container + ":" + mViewPager);
       CameraFragment fragment2 = (CameraFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
               .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager_container + ":" + mViewPager);

       if(fragment != null){
            fragment.displayMorePhotos();}

        if(fragment2 != null){
            fragment2.displayMorePhotos();}


    }

    private static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";
    private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 0;
    private static final int HOME_FRAGMENT = 1;

    private Context mContext = HomeActivity.this;

    //firebase
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    //widgets
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private FrameLayout mFrameLayout;
    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    public InterstitialAd Stack2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Stack2 = new InterstitialAd(mContext);
      //  Stack2.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8090166845540486/6763106401"); //real
        Stack2.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");  //fake
        MobileAds.initialize(mContext, "ca-app-pub-8090166845540486~5792871752");
        Stack2.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting.");
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_container);
        mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayoutParent);

        setupFirebaseAuth();

        initImageLoader();
        setupBottomNavigationView();
        setupViewPager();




        if (Stack2.isLoaded()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial is loaded.");
            Stack2.show();
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
        }

    }



    public void onCommentThreadSelected(Photo photo, String callingActivity){
        Log.d(TAG, "onCommentThreadSelected: selected a coemment thread");

        ViewCommentsFragment fragment  = new ViewCommentsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(getString(R.string.photo), photo);
        args.putString(getString(R.string.home_activity), getString(R.string.home_activity));
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(getString(R.string.view_comments_fragment));
        transaction.commit();

    }

    public void hideLayout(){
        Log.d(TAG, "hideLayout: hiding layout");
        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    public void showLayout(){
        Log.d(TAG, "hideLayout: showing layout");
        mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if(mFrameLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            showLayout();
        }
    }


    private void initImageLoader(){
        UniversalImageLoader universalImageLoader = new UniversalImageLoader(mContext);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(universalImageLoader.getConfig());
    }

    /**
     * Responsible for adding the 3 tabs: Camera, Home, Messages
     */
    private void setupViewPager(){
        SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new HomeFragment());//index 1
        adapter.addFragment(new CameraFragment());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

      //  tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_camera);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.followoo);
         tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.main);

    }





    /**
     * BottomNavigationView setup
     */
    private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
        BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext, this,bottomNavigationViewEx);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationViewEx.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    }


     /*
    ------------------------------------ Firebase ---------------------------------------------
     */

    /**
     * checks to see if the @param 'user' is logged in
     * @param user
     */
    private void checkCurrentUser(FirebaseUser user){
        Log.d(TAG, "checkCurrentUser: checking if user is logged in.");

        if(user == null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Setup the firebase auth object
     */
    private void setupFirebaseAuth(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupFirebaseAuth: setting up firebase auth.");

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                //check if the user is logged in
                checkCurrentUser(user);

                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(HOME_FRAGMENT);
        checkCurrentUser(mAuth.getCurrentUser());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ad is interstitial ad  then just use this:

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
 mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8090166845540486/6763106401");
```

If it is Banner ad then:

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8090166845540486/6763106401");
```

Comment: So it does not matter if ads are called in HomeFragment or HomeActivity class?

Comment: I don't think so.